# Kafka cluster on muliple nodes with docker-compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up Kafka cluster on 3 nodes, with docker-compose.

1. node:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.7.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.2=node2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=node3:2888:3888;2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.7.0
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: node1:2181,node2:2181,node3:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://node1:9095
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9095
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:4:1"
    ports:
      - 9095:9095
```

2. node:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.7.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=node1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.3=node3:2888:3888;2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.7.0
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: node1:2181,node2:2181,node3:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://node2:9095
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9095
      #KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:4:1"
    ports:
      - 9095:9095
```

3. node:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.7.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=node1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=node2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.7.0
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: node1:2181,node2:2181,node3:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://node3:9095
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9095
      #KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:4:1"
    ports:
      - 9095:9095
```

When I run it (on respective nodes):

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-node1.yml -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose-node2.yml -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose-node3.yml -d
```

If I check logs, there are no errors. On contrary I can see something like:

```
INFO Registered broker 1 at path /brokers/ids/1 ...
INFO Registered broker 2 at path /brokers/ids/2 ...
INFO Registered broker 3 at path /brokers/ids/3 ...
```

Two things that are strange, first on the first node where I try to create a topic, logs stop at

```
creating topics: test:4:1
Created topic test.
```

If I set up a single node (localhost) everything sets up just fine. The second thing is that node2 is always elected as controller.
This is what I get with kafkacat:

```
kafkacat -b node1:9095,node2:9095,node3:9095 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 2: node2:9095/2):
 3 brokers:
  broker 2 at node2:9095 (controller)
  broker 3 at node3:9095
  broker 1 at node1:9095
 1 topics:
  topic "test" with 4 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 2, replicas: 2, isrs: 2
    partition 1, leader 3, replicas: 3, isrs: 3
    partition 2, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 3, leader 2, replicas: 2, isrs: 2
```

But if I run:

```
docker exec -it kafka kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server node1:9095,node2:9095,node3:9095 --topic test --from-beginning
```

I get loads of warnings:

```
[2021-04-12 14:31:06,848] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-95791-1, groupId=console-consumer-95791] Received unknown topic or partition error in ListOffset request for partition test-2 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
```

and

```
[2021-04-12 14:31:06,848] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-95791-1, groupId=console-consumer-95791] Received unknown topic or partition error in ListOffset request for partition test-1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
```

Like there's no partition 1 and 2.

If I try to produce a message:

```
docker exec -it kafka-tn kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server tn00:9095,tn01:9095,tn02:9095 --topic test
```

I get loads of errors:

```
[2021-04-12 14:40:33,273] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 41 : {test=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Am I doing something crazy here or it's just some minor misconfiguration?

Comment: While this may be a valid setup, is there anything against using k3s and Strimzi Kafka operator or existing Helm Charts?

Comment: #OneCricketeer probably you meant k8s. Sure my life would be much easier with Kubernetes but unfortunately for now I have to deal with docker-compose.

Comment: I actually meant https://k3s.io/

Comment: OneCricketeer thanks for the tip, I'll check out k3s.io.